# Why use protocol, not call the method directly?

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, protocols, delegation

For eg: `UITableviewDelegate` protocol has `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. Why make it a delegate method in a protocol not a method in the `UITableView` class and call it directly?

Comment: So you don't have to subclass the entire UITableView class just to do a small little task like a custom cell. Also it allows you to de couple your code a lot better IMO.

Answer (score 4):

It is actually in the `UITableViewDataSource` not delegate which is an important distinction.

The purpose of **delegation** is to transfer responsibility for something to client code. The `UITableView` itself doesn't know what type of cells it needs to create. Your application is the one that knows what the cells are supposed to look like and how they function. This is why the `tableView` asks the dataSource (defined by a protocol) to create the cells.

In the Apple frameworks a `delegate` is usually for listening to object events and a `dataSource` is used to provide content for something. Both are forms of the delegation pattern.

If you are asking because you want to ask a table view - "What is the cell at that index path?" you **can** use the instance method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0):

Because you might want a different class to be the data-source for the table-view in your `UITableViewController`.

Here is a simple and somewhat contrived example to illustrate...

Imagine you have a view controller with two table views in it showing DataA and DataB and you can press a button next to each table to go to another view where that table is full-screen. You would set this up as a view controller with two `UITableView`s and two `UIButton`s and a second controller `MyFullScreenTableViewController` which is a `UITableViewController` subclass, then you would have two completely separate objects, one is the data source for the DataA table and one is the data source for the DataB table. So these objects provide the cells for both tables in the first view, and they also provide the cells in the full-screen controller - you could pass in the correct data-source depending on which table it is viewing.